# Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 freezes every time

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

When the **Install Updates** button is pressed in the Update Manager, the Update Manager freezes.

[image: Screenshot for explaining the issue]

Update and upgrade did not solve the issue.

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 475, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1622, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1696, in get_aptdaemon
    False),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 475, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1622, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1696, in get_aptdaemon
    False),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 473, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type, result.value, result.traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 52, in commit
    downgrade, defer=True)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

permissions in your python packages are possibly not working , change its permission by using-

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

-Replace USER with your login name, if this doesnt works check the output of -

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login
```

If it throw any error `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

then the reason behind this could be setup tools package has been deleted in my Python environment .to solve this use the following script-

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

hope it will work.

Comment: Its sometimes hard for others  to search exactly what they want, or they dont know for what they are looking for . So I have just tested it and as it worked , posted it. relating error to any workaround should be tested . thats what i did.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands as an alternative:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will run the updates for you, maybe after those are run your update manager will work.

Comment: sorry, but this did not solve the issue! Even I am not able to install any software using ubuntu software center

Comment: The answer can be found here   http://askubuntu.com/questions/383234/not-able-to-install-from-ubuntu-software-center

the same answer from the different problem

It works!