# Not able to install from ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

Not able to install any software from ubuntu software center. There is no response after pressing install button.

The error which I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/**init**.py", line 475, in
>   _inline_callbacks
>      result = gen.send(result)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1622, in
>   _run_transaction_helper
>
> daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1696, in 
>   get_aptdaemon
>      False),
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
>      follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in **init**
>      self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
>      self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in
>   start_service_by_name
>      'su', (bus_name, flags)))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
>      message, timeout)
>   dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch 
>   helper exited with unknown return code 1
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/**init**.py", line 475, in 
>   _inline_callbacks
>      result = gen.send(result)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1622, in 
>   _run_transaction_helper
>      daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1696, in 
>   get_aptdaemon
>      False),
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
>      follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in **init**
>      self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
>      self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in 
>   start_service_by_name
>      'su', (bus_name, flags)))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
>      message, timeout)
>
> dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch 
>   helper exited with unknown return code 1
>
> dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch 
>   helper exited with unknown return code 1

### Edit 1

New errors after running the command given in the answer.

I tried with sudo too.

A part of the error code

Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
Copying setuptools-1.4.1-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
setuptools 1.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
error: /usr/local/bin/easy_install: Permission denied
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.

Comment: don't remove python,it was necessary to boot ubuntu.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

permissions in your python packages are possibly not working , change its permission by using-

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

-Replace USER with your login name, if this doesnt works check the output of -

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login
```

If it throw any error `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

then the reason behind this could be setup tools package has been deleted in my Python environment .to solve this use the following script-

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

hope it will work.

Comment: it worked! thanks , i was able to install software but i was getting error as edited in question after running the curl command

Comment: you can now install trough Ubuntu Software Center ??

Comment: yes, but while running the curl ---- command it resulted in errors as added in the question

Comment: that was for if you failed in first line the one for chown. No issues your problem is solved.

Comment: While this "answer" may work, it is just bad advice. You shouldn't `chown -R $USER` system directories. And you shouldn't tell people to run arbitrary scripts off the Internet.

Comment: Sir , is there any safe method?? if yes let me know , then i will keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: I agree with @dobey. While it may fix the issue changing permissions in system folders is a bad idea. Plus "fixing" an issue like this does not really get to the root cause